# Implementing save button in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget, android-manifest

Hi
I am developing an android app which is accessed by entering by a 4 digit PIN
I have the following doubts

1) whenever i start the app I present a login screen and on entering the PIN, a form is shown which is filled by the user. 
While filling the form if the user gets a call or notification, app closes with the data entered saved. Again when the user opens the app it directly shows the form but not the login screen. 
I want login screen to be shown and when user logins back and should have the data he entered before interruption.

2)When the user is in form if he presses back key it goes back to the login screen which is undesirable.
so I added finish() to the login screen activity but it leads to another problem. 
whenever I rotate the phone, screen is closed and i have again start the app then i get login screen in portrait mode. How to avoid this bug.

3) I have a datepicker in my form. How can I store its value as a string? Or in any other variable

4)In the form I have to make sure all the fields are filled
So I am doing error checking by seeing if the field is filled
But how to notify the user other than using the TOAST method.
I want the message given to the user to be dynamic like it should check all the fields and notify the missing fields in one single message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store the data. Do the saving in `onPause()` method of your activity.
Or you can use th built-in mechanism of savedBundleState.

2) You can restrict you form activity of switching the mode to lanscape using attribute in your manifest in activity tag: `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`.

3) Read the day, month and year and store them in preferences.

4) Use Dialog. Check the fields and then show the [`AlertDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) with error messages.

Comment: Hi my second question plz it is really bothering me

Comment: One more thing is it possible to use datepicker inline or we can get only through dialog box?

Comment: AFAIK, it is not, but you always have android sources =)

Comment: Hay sorry for bothering was able to use it inline                                                            //Date                                                               DatePicker date=(DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.dp); mDay=date.getDayOfMonth();                                          mMonth=date.getMonth();                                             mYear=date.getYear();

Comment: great. If this answer helped you, mark is as accepted by clicking a tick to the left of the answer.